# VMWare ESXi slow file copy to guest

Tags: vmware-esxi, network-speed

When I copy a file from a physical Windows 7 machine over to a Windows Server guest on a VMWare ESXi the file copy is fast for a few seconds but then drops down to a crawl of 3Mbps. Everything is on a Gbps network. How do I speed up my network connection?

I've googled a lot about it, but haven't found anyone with a solution for quite the same scenario.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a write IO issue on your Windows Server VM - what storage type is the datastore that it's sitting on? How many other VM's are running on the same ESXi server and what are they doing on that particular datastore?

Comment: There are 3 VMs on the same host and datastor, but they are mostly idle. Mostly the whole host is idle. The datastore is on a regular SATA drive. Its a small lab network of 2 physical computers. I tried shutting down 2 VMs and only have one running, but the problem remains.

Comment: Would the server VM happen to be a domain controller?

Comment: You are you using thin provisioning, aka, drive space is allocated on demand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to speed up file copying onto a VMWare virtual server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9384/how-to-speed-up-file-copying-onto-a-vmware-virtual-server)

Answer (score 1):

Check your vhardware network adapter, use vmxnet3 or e1000.